# Installing SharePoint 2010 Foundation problem?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm having a problem with SharePoint 2010 Foundation in German. I've Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Host and virtual machine with same system. In that virtual machine right after starting installer, progress bar shows up and error message is displayed 'fehler beim installieren dieses packets' which google translates to: 'error when installing this packets'. I am not german so hard to say if it's correct translation. The funny thing is I've downloaded english version of SharePoint 2010 Foundation and it shows up some gui (prerequisites) correctly, so there's clearly something wrong with that german version, and Google search says nothing about it. I've tried to use that German Sharepoint on 2ndary virtual server and it failed as well so it's not related to this particular VM (still it's same Host thou).

I've even downloaded that German version to my Win 7 x64 Enterprise and it started without problem so it doesn't seem like the package is broken on Microsoft servers.

Anyone got any ideas? Server is only 2nd Domain Controller with DNS and SQL Express R2 installed. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like SharePoint Foundation 2010 German is broken on some Microsoft servers. My friend helped me and downloaded it to different location and it was also bad. I downloaded it at home and moved to server and it works fine. So something is shady on Microsoft servers.